# Migration from Interwoven Sitepoint to SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, migration

We are analyzing the possibilities to migrate content from interwoven sitepoint to Tridion 2013.

Not sure if migration of just the content here can be achieved through automated tool or manual process.

Few questions -

1. What could be the approach ?
2. Any experiences with this kind of migration ?

Appreciate inputs on both manual and automated migration (if possible)

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you planning to migrate exactly (just content, or web pages, or complete sites), what have you found out already, are you thinking of a manual or automated migration, or a combination..

Comment: My 2 cents: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html

Comment: edited the question to be more specific :)

Comment: Bart's 2 cents:  http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/how-to-say-goodbye-to-your-migration-tool

Comment: This is a very open question that is unlikely to have a good, reusable answer.

Answer (score 3):

Migration is the intersection between:

- Content inventory
- Skills or expertise
- Time

You really can't analyze the challenge without a content inventory and model for the source and target systems. Ideally "Inventory x time" is greater than the cost of skills or expertise.

Gotchas in a move:

- Dependencies. **If Content Porter seems challenging, do not automate.**
- Rich text is "**XML in the XHTML namespace**."
- Tridion identifiers are unique between **DTAP** environments and are *managed*.

Take advantage of:

- **Page Types**. One click creates a page, creates and adds content, and publishes. You can configure and change a Page Type faster than defining the requirements for some type of automation.
- **Managed selections**. Categories & Keywords may be better than plain text fields and "Booleans."
- Most migrations I've seen need several passes. Consider scripts to reset and/or redo imports.

And if considering a tool, ask about basic SDL Tridion concepts like managed links and BluePrinting. I've asked one vendor about BluePrinting and the response was, "I've *heard* of it." That's not a good sign.

Comment: +1 for the Page Types solution! Having the intended editorial organization create the site in Tridion will also double as an intensive training-on-the-job.

Answer (score 2):

SDL Tridion has very comprehensive APIs to interface with the content management system, making the import of content from external sources quite straight forward (research Core Service)

I am not familiar with Interwoven Sitepoint's API, so I cannot comment on the ease of extracting data from your existing CMS.

As posted above, by Bart, also seriously consider the manual approach to migration vs. automation. Often it can be more cost effective and yield a higher quality output.

The temptation in a migration is to move the website/content over "as is". This is often a mistake. Take the migration as an opportunity to both cleanup/restructure content and investigate the strengths and differences in the new CMS platform.

Consider things like Content Model, Component based CMS approach, separation of content and design, BluePrinting, Translation etc. during the migration and it will save you a lot of time in the future vs. a quick lift and shift approach.

Comment: +1 for manual migration as a serious part of the plan.  +100 for giving the website a haircut in the move.

Answer (score 1):

We did migrated many CMS like Word press, Navi CMS and Tridion R5.2 websites to SDL Tridion 2011 and 2013 using Tridion Core Services.

Best practice you can identify your contents Like news, events, press releases this can be automated to migrate.

Those schema content's you can write logic to export all your content as XML.

Using core services and Events system you can able to create the component and pages dynamically including your multimedia stuff.

In core services you may know which content types has to be use which schema based on the mapping you can able to write a core service logic to migrate your contents other stuffs like designs like Page template and Component any way you have to do it by manually.

Content pages like About us, terms and conditions and privacy pages are very minimal so those contents you can manually you create.

Even I did migrated Tridion R4 to Tridion R5. we wrote a small migration tool interface to have a mapping for Tridion R4 DDT to schema mapping. all the template mapping we did exported all the content as xml.. we did provided interface to read the XML and imported to Tridion R5 successfully.